# How to apply rules per IP on IPTables?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

How can I make these rule apply per IP instead of globally? If one IP sends more than 2 packets per second, all packets for all IPs get dropped, I need it to only drop the packets of the IP that is sending more than 2 packets per second.

I first apply these set of rules:

```
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 7778 -m string --hex-string "|5341 4d50|" --algo kmp -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7778 -m string --hex-string "|5341 4d50|" --algo kmp -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I apply these:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7778 -m string --hex-string "|5341 4d50|" --algo kmp -j DROP

/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 7778 -m string --hex-string "|5341 4d50|" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused, what should I do ? I don't get it, could you explain me, please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hashlimit module.

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --dport 7778 -m string --hex-string "|5341 4d50|" --algo kmp  -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 2/sec --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-name foo -j DROP
```

Here --hashlimit-mode does the trick. See manual below

> --hashlimit-mode {srcip|srcport|dstip|dstport},...
>
> A comma-separated list of objects to take into consideration. If no --hashlimit-mode option is given, hashlimit acts
>   like limit, but at the expensive of doing the hash housekeeping.

For example, you can set your rate for per source ip - destination port pair like

--hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport

Comment: I applied the rule but it doesn't seem to be working. I can send more than 2 packets and it wont drop them. I also made sure by sending ridiculous amounts of packets (to simulate an attack) and all of them went through and the game server responded.

Comment: @Muschel you probable have problem with string match